# How to achieve the method of controller that will be requested by client in interceptor of Spring MVC

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, request, interceptor

I have a requirement of achieving the method of controller in interceptor and the object returned by the method in interceptor.

why?

Because I want to declare the datatype which will return to client using annotation annotated on the method. for example :

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
@RequestMapping("/hello/")
public class HelloWorld {
    @ResponseType(DataType.JSON)
    @RequestMapping(value="/{username}")
    public UserInfo hellowUser(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
         UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
         userInfo.setUsername(username);
         return userInfo.
    }
}
```

then interceptor:

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throw Exception {
    Method method = getRequestedMethod();
    Object result = getResultReturnedByTheMethod();
    ResponseType responseType = method.getAnnotation(ResponseType.class);
    DataType type = responseType.value();
    swich(type) {
    case DataType.JSON : writeJson(result);
    case .......
    ...
    }
}
```

So, in another words,  how can I implement the "getRequestedMethod" and "getResultReturnedByTheMethod" correctly?

Comment: Spring MVC is capable of handling JSON output on its own (without you needing to write a custom interceptor for it) using `@ResponseBody`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Jackson processor? http://jackson.codehaus.org/

It automatically converts JSON to and from the controller. And is supported by Spring MVC.